# Suggestion about populate the same html item (with different values) client side, because server side serialization block it

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, object

I have this item-html template :

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="data1"></div>
    <div class="data2"></div>
    <div class="data3"></div>
    <div class="data4"></div>
    <div class="data5"></div>
    <div class="data6"></div>
</div>
```

and my data is serialized in a Javascript object (get by JSON) from the server.

I have something like 1000 JS objects for example and I need to append 1000 of these html items, each with data for each object.

Cycling and appending them client side with javascript is very intensive! I want to create the whole html on the server side (with a big redundance, as I send the html tag for each item) and print them but it is impossible, because these objects are serialized from C#, and I get a maxJsonLength exception.

So what do you suggest to get round this issue?

Answer (score 3):

It won't be too heavy to simply loop through the JSON and populate/append each div.  One suggestion I would make would be to be sure you are adding to an element that is outside the DOM so that you aren't causing 1000 repaints.  Once the final object is populated, add it to the DOM so only a single repaint occurs.

Comment: What do you mean "outside of the DOM"?

Comment: create an element but do not attach it to any elements that are shown on the page and populate it, then attach.

Comment: tried with `var htmlSede=$('#templateSede').html(); htmlSediCompleta.append(htmlSede);` for each cycle, but I get htmlSediCompleta.append is not a function. I need to declare as "html object"?

Comment: `htmlSediCompleta=htmlSediCompleta+htmlSede` it is too heavy

Answer (score 1):

In order to add your data items outside the DOM, you could do something like this:

```
var item = $('<div/>'); // Creates a new parent div outside the DOM
for(...) {
    item.append(/* your parsed JSON data as HTML */);
}
$('#parentDivInsideDOM').append(item);
```

What you're doing there is creating a parent div outside the DOM, appending your internal data divs in a loop (still outside the DOM), and then appending the whole thing to a parent div inside the DOM for 1 repaint.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending each div, look into `.html()`, and insert it that way.

That's much less resource intensive.

Comment: Check Skylar's answer, I believe his approach is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Client side scripting is the way to go here .. use something like [json2html](http://json2html.com) or jTemplates.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://json2html.com/js/jquery.json2html-2.5-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var transform = {tag:'div',class:'item',children:[
                    {tag:'div',class:'data1',html:'.data1'},
                    {tag:'div',class:'data2',html:'.data2'},
                    {tag:'div',class:'data3',html:'.data3'},
                    {tag:'div',class:'data4',html:'.data4'},
                    {tag:'div',class:'data5',html:'.data5'},
                    {tag:'div',class:'data6',html:'.data6'}
                ]};

$.json2html(json,transform);
</script>
```

that is assuming your json object looks as follows

```
var json =  
   [{data1:'data1',data2:'data2',data3:'data3',data4:'data4',data5:'data5',data6:'data6'},
   {data1:'data1',data2:'data2',data3:'data3',data4:'data4',data5:'data5',data6:'data6'},
   {data1:'data1',data2:'data2',data3:'data3',data4:'data4',data5:'data5',data6:'data6'}];
```